Installing Jekyll on my M3 Macbook won't "stick"
I think I have painted myself into a corner trying to override the default Ruby install so that I can install Jekyll.
Here is a rough timeline:

I follow this tutorial to the letter and it works, my site is up
I install this theme, rebuild my site, and deploy successfully with Netlify
I start changing the site's configuration wrt layouts, menus, links, etc. Nothing related directly to Jekyll or Ruby configuration.
I try jekyll build and get jekyll not found
I try reinstalling Jekyll with gem install jekyll and get
Successfully installed jekyll-4.3.3 
1 gem installed
I try which jekyll to check installation and get jekyll not found
I ask Gemini for help and it tells me to try these commands in sequence for a clean install gem uninstall jekyll, sudo gem clean system, gem install jekyll --no-document
I quit and reopen my terminal and again try which jekyll and again get jekyll not found.
Because there are Jekyll items in gem list, Gemini advises that I probably have an environment variable issue and tells me to fix it by adding a line like export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/jekyll/bin" to my .zshrc file. I try to do this by finding the path with gem path but there are no Jekyll gem paths.
Gemini suggests I try installing Jekyll using rbenv so I do that and receive the following message
Setting up your shell with `rbenv init zsh' ...
writing ~/.zprofile: now configured for rbenv.
but there is no reference to rbenv in my .zprofile file

I am on a pretty new laptop so I am considering resetting to factory settings because this seems pretty intractable, but I am brand new to Ruby and Jekyll so I am posting here to see if there are any less drastic solutions. The pre-installed Ruby on mac seems to be just a huge pain!

Homebrew doesn't seem to be such a great solution for installing Ruby because, based on the video, it does not keep gem binaries in the PATH automatically. This is likely why you failed to find the jekyll command: it was installed, but it was not in the PATH.
I suggest you uninstall the Homebrew Ruby. Clean up any references to Ruby in your .zprofile and .zshrc. And then try and get rbenv working from scratch. No need to factory reset, because the only thing you really did, if you followed the video, was install Homebrew. No damage was done.

If you can you should post your .zprofile and .zshrc in the question, if you are unsure which lines are significant in those files. Also you do run Zsh as your shell, I assume (echo $SHELL)?

Take a look in your ~/.zshrc file, also call which ruby and see that it's using the one that is in your PATH var, also check gem in a similar way to see.
Another thing I would try is calling bundle exec jekyll serve and see if that changes the output in a way that helps point you in the right question.

@casper @jp Thank you both for your help so far!
I do run Zsh as my shell. I tried calling bundle exec and got:
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory, makes sense.
I tried uninstalling homebrew ruby and got Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby, which also makes sense I guess.I also installed rbenv.
contents of .zshrc:
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@3.0/bin:$PATH"
contents of .zprofile:
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"  # Added by rbenv init on Wed Jul 17 21:37:35 PDT 2024 eval "$(rbenv init - --no-rehash zsh)"


Please edit your question and add you .zshrc and .zprofile there. It's much easier to read them that way. Always add code by editing the question. Do not put code in the comments. 2) Remove the homebrew ruby 3.0 line from your .zshrc. 3) After these steps to me it looks like rbenv should be set up correctly. Please read the rbenv docs and install a Ruby version, and then you can install jekyll and all the rest.


related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78666172/214446

@Caspar thank you for the directive about adding code to the post instead of the comment, I did not realize that's the way things are done. You probably got a bunch of notifications as I kept struggling to make my comment more legible so my apologies for that.

Don't worry, you really shouldn't have to reset anything! You're correct that the built-in Ruby is a pain, as is the Homebrew Ruby. When I started out I got the most cryptic errors and they confused me for days!
As others have mentioned in the comments, a version manager like rbenv is a great idea! I personally really like mise right now. It's a polyglot version manager, so it handles basically any language, Ruby included. (asdf is another very popular polyglot version manager, but I recently switched to mise because I like its CLI better and it feels faster to me.) You can install mise with Homebrew: brew install mise.
The next element is zsh's init files, again as discussed in the comments. These can get kind of confusing, but here's a list of which files are read and executed when. I keep most of my configuration in .zshrc, but note that it's only executed for interactive zsh sessions.
These are the two pertinent lines in my .zshrc file:
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
eval "$(mise activate zsh)"

Since mise is installed with Homebrew, it's important that the Homebrew paths are added before calling mise activate zsh, because otherwise the mise executable won't be found.
Once you've added those lines to your .zshrc (or .zprofile or whichever relevant file from the list), make sure to refresh your shell session to pick up the changes: you can just close the Terminal window and open a new one, or you can run exec zsh (which replaces the current zsh process with a new one). You can make sure that mise is in your $PATH by running whence mise.
From there, using mise is super easy: cd to the directory of your project and run mise use ruby@latest (or, even better, mise use ruby@3.3.4 or whatever version you'd like, so your version is pinned). mise will install Ruby and will update $PATH to use the specified version. You can check this by running whence -a ruby; you should get something like this:
$ whence -a ruby
/Users/you/.local/share/mise/installs/ruby/latest/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

Now your mise-installed Ruby is in front of the system Ruby, and you're all set!
Hopefully this is at least a little helpful, and sorry this is so long!

Thank you so much! Your answer was so incredibly helpful! I was able to implement it exactly as you described on my personal laptop. My work laptop apparently didn't have libyaml installed which caused mise install ruby@latest to fail. brew install libyaml is all that was needed. Thank you again!

@cmp You're welcome! I'm so glad it helped! That's really great; I'm glad it worked :) and thanks for the kind message too; that was very nice of you to reply!
